# Why is my dynamic title not working in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I created this component for meta tags, here is a sample:

```
import React from "react";
const Meta = ({ pageTitle, desc }) => {
return (
 <>
  <meta charSet="utf-8" />
  <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="Author" content="Luteya Coulston Namasa" />
  <meta name="description" content={desc}/>
  <title>{`Luteya Coulston | ${pageTitle}`}</title>
</>
);
};

export default Meta;
```

The problem I'm facing is that it shows all the tags while still loading but after completely loading tags like `title` rewrites to `<title></title>`  and `Open Graph protocol` gets removed completely. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap them in next/head

```
<Head>
  <meta charSet="utf-8" />
  <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="Author" content="Luteya Coulston Namasa" key="author"/>
  <meta name="description" content={desc}/>
  <title>{`Luteya Coulston | ${pageTitle}`}</title>
</Head>
```

if you are using the same meta tag, add a key so it's not repeated.

Default tags should be used in  in _app.js. og:tags, title and description etc should be used in your pages

Comment: Thanks that worked I don't know how I missed that. I'll try and refactor the way you explained.

Comment: remember to use "key"